# Adding on an Ajax/Jquery frontend client to web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have an existing web service created in java. I would like to add an Ajax jquery based client.

Controller class:

```
public class CourseController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String ADD_UPDATE = "/course.jsp";
    private static String ADD = "/course.jsp";
    private static String LIST_COURSES = "/listCourses.jsp";
    private static String LIST_COURSE_JSON = "/WEB-INF/Results/course-json.jsp";
    private static String LIST_COURSE_XML = "/WEB-INF/Results/course-xml.jsp";
    private static String LIST_COURSE_STRING = "/WEB-INF/Results/course-string.jsp";

    private CourseDao dao;

    /** 
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CourseController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        try {
            dao = new CourseDao();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String forward = "";
            String action = request.getParameter( "action" );

            // decide which viewer to use based on format parameter
            String format = request.getParameter("format");
            if (format==null) format = "json";
            forward = LIST_COURSE_JSON;
            if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("xml")) forward = LIST_COURSE_XML;
            else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("string")) forward = LIST_COURSE_STRING;

            System.out.println("In course controller doGet, action is >"+action+"< format requested is >"+format+"<");

            if(action.equalsIgnoreCase( "delete" ) ){
                 String Courseid = request.getParameter("courseid");
                dao.deleteCourse(Courseid);
                request.setAttribute("courses", dao.getAllCourses() );
            }
            else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "edit" ) ) {
                forward = ADD_UPDATE;
                String Courseid = request.getParameter("courseid");
                Courses course = dao.getCourseById(Courseid);
                request.setAttribute("course", course);
            }
            else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "insert" ) ) {
                forward = LIST_COURSE_JSON;
                String Courseid = request.getParameter("courseid");
                String coursename = request.getParameter("coursename");
                String faculty = request.getParameter("faculty");
                String courseSpecification = request.getParameter("coursespecification");
                String duration = request.getParameter("duration");
                Courses course = new Courses(Courseid,coursename, faculty, courseSpecification, duration);
                System.out.println("In courseController insert: course received is: "+course.toString());
                int rowsInserted = dao.addCourse(course);
                System.out.println("In courseController: I managed to insert "+rowsInserted +" records");
                // place the newly inserted course into request block so it can be used if needed by 
                // after module
                List<Courses> courseList = new ArrayList<Courses>();
                courseList.add(course);
                request.setAttribute("courses", courseList);

            }
            else if( action.equalsIgnoreCase( "findcourse" ) ) {
                String coursename = request.getParameter("coursename");
                request.setAttribute("courses",dao.findCourse(coursename) );

            }
            else {

                DataTableObject dataTableObject = new DataTableObject();
//              // Pass Array containing DB data into our DataTable Object
                dataTableObject.setAaData(dao.getAllCourses());
//              // Convert dataTable object to JSON
//              // Pretty Printing to make JSON easier to read in the JSP page.
                Gson gson1 = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

                request.setAttribute("courses", dao.getAllCourses() );
            }
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher( forward );
            view.forward(request, response);
        }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request,response);
/*      Courses course= new Courses("", "", "", "", "");
        course.setCoursename( request.getParameter( "coursename" ) );
        course.setFaculty( request.getParameter( "faculty" ) );
        course.setCourseSpecification( request.getParameter( "courseSpecification" ) );
        course.setDuration(  request.getParameter( "duration" )  );
        String courseid = request.getParameter("courseid");

        if( courseid == null || courseid.isEmpty() )
            dao.addCourse(course);
        else {
            course.setCourseid( courseid );
            dao.updateCourse(course);
        }


        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher( LIST_COURSES);
        request.setAttribute("courses", dao.getAllCourses());
        view.forward(request, response);
*/        
    }

}
```

Presently it just communicates json xml or text.

I have attempted to create an ajax table object but the table displays loading... and no errors are given